# Vuetify: align the head of an expansion panel to the right

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to use the Vuetify expansion panel and align part of the content inside the `<div slote="head"></div>` to the right in order to get this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbOL8.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/22NTS.jpg

but i get this instead:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkMw0.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5k8ff.jpg

I tried

```css
float:right , text-align:right
```

even negative margins without success.

Comment: inside the <div slot="header">

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read
[what this site is about](https://stackoverflow.com/about) and 
"[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)" 
before asking a question. Please provide a [mcve]. Just posting links to screenshots on other sites isn't how you ask a question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was this line of CSS somewhere overriding my own CSS.

```
.v-expansion-panel__header > .v-expansion-panel__header__icon {
  flex: 1 1 auto !important;
}
```

Deleting it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Important:** It seems like your expansion panel is not getting full width

This is what you are looking for:

```
<div slot="header">
  <v-layout row>
    <v-flex xs8>
      Item
    </v-flex>
    <v-flex xs4 text-xs-right>
      Item
    </v-flex>
  </v-layout>
</div>
```

Working example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vbVxaa